# What is the best way output the name of the class who's method is being called?

Tags: objective-c, class, inheritance, logging

I am aware of NSStringFromClass.

My question relates to the situation where the same method is implemented in multiple classes in an inheritance tree, and you want to debugging information as to which class it is executing from.

Example:

Let us have three classes: A-->B-->C , inheriting as displayed by the arrows.

If each of them has a method foo(), defined:

```
-(void) foo
{
 // Do some work particular to the class it is in.
  .....
  //Each method ends with the debugging statement:
  NSLog("In foo of class:%$",NSClassFromString([self class]));
}
```

The problem occurs when foo of Class B, calls [super foo]. When [super foo] (i.e. Class A) reaches the NSLog statement, [self class] returns class B, and not A.

Likewise if C called [super foo], the log statement in super would log class C.

What I want to do, is output the class whose method implementation is being executed - so if class B calls [super foo], then the log statement in [A foo] outputs Class A.

The simple way is to replace NSClassFromString with a hardcoded string representing the class name, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` to include both the class and the method name:

```
NSLog(@"Greetings from %s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
```

I don't believe that there is a compiler-time macro for just the class name.

Answer (score 1):

There might not be a macro for class, but there is `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` macros in the C language. They expand to the current file and line number. You can use them in NSLog. I use `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` when I remember it, but I remember `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` more.

Example:

```
NSLog( @"%s %d", __FILE__, __LINE__ );
```

Remember that `__FILE__` isn’t an Objective-C string.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem occurs when foo of Class B, calls [super foo]. When [super
>   foo] (i.e. Class A) reaches the NSLog statement, [self class] returns
>   class B, and not A.

Sure. That's because `self` points to an object, and that object's class doesn't change just because you call a method of the superclass.

> The simple way is to replace NSClassFromString with a hardcoded string
>   representing the class name, but I was wondering if there is a better
>   way to do this?

As others have pointed out, you can use a macro like `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, but I think the simple and obvious approach is the best. You know the name of the class when you're writing the code, so you can write:

```
NSLog("In foo of class: %@", @"ClassA");
```

Each of your classes has its own implementation of your method, so each one can print its own class name in the message. Something like `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is useful when you're writing a debug macro that you're going to use in multiple functions. That's not the case here. Using the obvious approach makes it that much easier to see what's going on, and that's important during debugging (which I assume is what you're trying to do here).

Answer (score 0):

i think you would have to walk up the class hierarchy using `class_getSuperclass` and `class_getInstanceMethod`, comparing differences in the methods. do that to determine the objc class, then use `class_getName` or `NSStringFromClass` to get its name.

This would look something like:

```
NSString* MONClassNameWhichImplementsMethod(id Self, SEL cmd);
```

and

```
- (void)method
{
  NSLog(@"%@ - %@",
    MONGetClassWhichImplementsMethod(self, _cmd),
    NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)
  );
}
```

and

```
// NOT COMPILED -- FOR ILLUSTRATION ONLY
Class MONClassWhichImplementsMethod(Class cls, SEL cmd) {
  assert(cls && cmd && "srsly?");

  Class super = class_getSuperclass(cls);
  Method m1 = class_getInstanceMethod(cls, cmd);
  assert(m1 && "srsly?");

  Method m2 = class_getInstanceMethod(super, cmd);
  if (0 == m2) {
    return cls;
  }
  else if (m1 != m2) {
    return cls;
  }
  else {
    return MONClassWhichImplementsMethod(super, cmd);
  }
}

NSString* MONClassNameWhichImplementsMethod(id Self, SEL cmd) {
  return NSStringFromClass(MONClassNameWhichImplementsMethod(Self.class, cmd));
}
```

if it blows up from deep recursion, you've another problem.